# how not to generate red box in flutter, android studio,

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

how not to generate a red box in flutter when create widgets??

it`s so super annoying

I`ve been searching this for a while

but still couldn`t figure it out

can anyone help this please?

[image]

Comment: i cant see the full code, but widget names usually start with uppercase

Comment: @Zvi Karp when you create widgets using alt + enter it always appear like this

Comment: I don't think you can remove this, since the purpose of it is that you complete with an widget, since you just said (through alt+enter) "give me a widget snippet"

Comment: @Fernando in the case you mention just leaving the word "Widget" selected would be good enough; it's not clear what the red box adds to that. I find it super annoying.

Answer (score 8):

When you create widget using Context Actions, it seems Android Studio holds onto this widget and shows this with a red box. You can get rid of this grip by typing a `<TAB>` on any empty space.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> Color Scheme -> General -> Live Templates -> Active Segment -> Uncheck the Effects parameter then APPLY.

[image: Filedasd]