# How to disable the redbox in Android Studio?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

The red box i am referring to is described in the question below.

[how not to generate red box in flutter, android studio,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60663328/how-not-to-generate-red-box-in-flutter-android-studio)

Someone has suggested to press  to get rid of the red box - it does work but is there anyway to disable this red box from appearing in the first place?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable this by going into **Settings > Editor > General > Code Completion**, then uncheck **Insert default argument values in completions**.

[image: disable red box]

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comment.  It doesn't seem working.   https://imgur.com/a/oALZokh.  screen shot uploaded

Comment: @user2983167 This can turn off some of them. Still haven't found a way to turn off _all_.